# ASP.NET 4.5 TryUpdateModel not picking Form values in WebForm using Master-Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms, master-pages

I am using WebForms and I am trying to perform Model Validation inside a Master-Page and for some reason the model is not picking up the values, meaning that after the validation fires if I enter a good value, the model keeps coming back empty hence triggering the validation over and over. If I put the code in page without Master-Page it works fine. I was able to put a very simple example and honestly, it's hard to believe that as common as MasterPages are, nobody has ran into this scenario so far. For the purpose of this example I embedded the Model in the Code Behind but having outside makes no different. Any idea will be greatly welcome. Thanks.

--Master-Page--

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.master.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

-- WebForm --

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/test.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test3.aspx.cs" Inherits="test3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary" runat="server" />
    </div>
        <div><label>First Name:</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" id="FirstName" runat="server" /></div>
        <div><label>Middle Name:</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" id="MiddleName" runat="server" /></div>
        <div><label>Last Name:</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" id="LastName" runat="server" /></div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  Text="Submit" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

-- Code Behind --

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


public partial class test3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class testClass2
    {
        [Required()]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            testClass2 tc = new testClass2();
            if (TryUpdateModel(tc, new FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext)))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone who stumbles across this question and the answers below both of the answers combined will help you achieve that you need.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is indeed caused by usage of the master page. When used outside of the [data bound control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-bound-controls) (such as `GridView`, `FormView`, `Menu`, etc.), `FormValueProvider` expects to have the same keys in `Request.Form` dictionary as property names in model object.

If you will take a closer look at generated HTML you will see that all `input` tags in form with master page have `name` attribute value set to something like `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FirstName`, `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LastName`, etc. while form without master page leaves name attribute intact and equal to the value of control's `ID` property.

This is the way of how [`UniqueID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is generated to avoid name duplication (which should be avoided because in Web Forms we can have only one `form` tag and thus have controls with same `ID's` both on master page and form page).

And this is the cause why `FormValueProvider` cannot get values for  your `testClass2` object, it just cannot find `FirstName`, `LastName`, `MiddleName` values in posted form.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.You can write a little front-end code to set the `name` equal to `id` and don't forget to set `ClientIDMode` to `Static`

```
<script>
    $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         $(this).attr("name", id);
    });
</script>
```