# FormValueProvider unable to pick up form value with master page

Tags: asp.net

I'm using TryUpdateModel(reviewResult, new FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext) to get data from form.
But it doesn't work when using master page.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082754/asp-net-4-5-tryupdatemodel-not-picking-form-values-in-webform-using-master-page),  i understand it's because master page changes the ID. Is there any solution/workaround for it?

Comment: I know this question has been asked a while ago, and you have referenced an answer, but there is a working answer in that link and I have successfully used it.